# Concurrency issue in JPA and JTA

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [concurrency (stale data) problem in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975821/concurrency-stale-data-problem-in-jpa)

Sorry for duplicating, but I think I didn't get satisfactory answers so posting again
Let's say I have methods with following signature

```
Object getData(int id) {  
  //create a entity manager
  //get data frm db
  //return data
}

updateData() {
  Object obj = getData(id) 
  //get entity manager
  //start transcation tx
  //update
  //commit tx
}
```

Now will it cause concurrency issue? Can data be stale in worst case? E.g.
    if I `getData` and by the time I update, if someone updates the data will my `updateData` will have stale data?
Now can i use  following:Will i solve the problem?

```
Object getData(int id,Entitymanager em) {  

      //get data frm db using em
      //return data
    }

 updateData() {
      Object obj = getData(id) 
      //get entity manager em
      //start transcation tx
      //getdata using getData(id,em)
      //commit tx
    }
```

Comment: Two different EMs on the same object is probably not a good idea.

Comment: If you didn't get satisfactory answers, let people know why they aren't satisfactory and maybe clarify your question. Posting the same question won't help, work on it. Voting to close.

Comment: Yes, please just edit the original question instead of posting duplicates.  Editing will bump it back to the top of the "Active" page, so it will get more views.

Answer (score 0):

If two separate requests access `updateData()` concurrently you may get stale data. You may handle the staleness by locking the fetched data in `updateData()`. If you're using Hibernate as your JPA provider you can lock the data as follows:

```
updateData() {
    Object obj = getData(id);
    Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
    session.refresh(obj, LockMode.UPGRADE);
}
```

The refresh is necessary because it may happen that between the fetching and the locking of the data another transaction completes in `updateData`.

Please keep in mind that the entity manager used in `getData` and `updateData` must be the same.